# Model binding with nested child models and PartialViews in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model, model-binding

I have the following types and classes:

```
namespace MVC.Models

public class Page 
{
   public EditableContent Content {get; set; }
}

public class EditableContent
{
    public TemplateSection SidebarLeft {get; set; }
    public TemplateSection SidebarRight {get; set; }
}
```

I want to edit the `Page` instance in my `Edit.aspx` View. Because `EditableContent` is also attached to other models, I have a `PartialView` called `ContentEditor.ascx` that is strongly typed and takes an instance of `EditableContent` and renders it.

The rendering part all works fine, but when I post - everything inside my `ContentEditor` is not binded - which means that `Page.Content` is `null`.

On the PartialView, I use strongly typed Html Helpers to do this:

```
<%= Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TemplateId) %>
```

But because the input elements on the form that are rendered by `ContentEditor.ascx` does not get the `Content` prefix to its `id` attribute - the values are not binded to `Page`.

I tried using loosely typed helpers to overcome this:

```
<%= Html.Hidden("Content.TemplateId", Model.TemplateId) %>
```

And when I'm dealing with a property that is a `List<T>` of something it gets very ugly. I then have to render collection indexes manually.

Should I put both Page and EditableContent as parameters to the controller action?:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Page page, EditableContent content) { ... }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the `EditorFor` helper

Model:

```
public class EditableContent
{
    public string SidebarLeft { get; set; }
    public string SidebarRight { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    public EditableContent Content { get; set; }
}
```

Views/Home/Index.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ToDD.Models.Page>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%-- 
    This is the important part: It will look for 
    Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/EditableContent.ascx
    and render it. You could also specify a prefix
    --%>
    <%= Html.EditorFor(page => page.Content, "Content") %>
    <input type="submit" value="create" />
<% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/EditableContent.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ToDD.Models.EditableContent>" %>

<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SidebarLeft) %>
<br/>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SidebarRight) %>
```

And finally Controller/HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        var page = new Page
        {
            Content = new EditableContent
            {
                SidebarLeft = "left",
                SidebarRight = "right"
            }
        };
        return View(page);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Page page)
    {
        return View(page);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, dude! Thanks. I assume that the EditorFor takes care of all the scaffolding to tie everything together.

Comment: I have done this on a project of mine, but can you explain why `Html.RenderPartial("_blah" , Model.Blah)` doesn't work Darin? As that's what we previously had.

Comment: @GONeale, it doesn't work because you pass Model.Blah, so inside the partial you are in the context of Blah, not in the context of Model => all helpers that you use in this partial generate wrong input names. Editor templates are different => they take into account the parent context and generate helpers that are used inside them will generate proper input names. Just look at your markup and you will immediately see the difference. For the default model binder to work you must respect the conventions.