# Model binding with nested child models and PartialViews in ASP.NET MVC (continued...)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the same problem outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462506/model-binding-with-nested-child-models-and-partialviews-in-asp-net-mvc).  That is, nested view models in an editor where the child model is not bound correctly on submit.  Unfortunately, the EditorFor technique described won't work for me because EditorFor drops in some div's around the specified template that make my rendered page look weird.  Any other ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editor Templates solve this issue.